# Autostart Midori with multiple tabs

Tags: raspbian, boot, midori

I need Midori to autostart and open two tabs to different addresses when the RPi boots.
The Pi im working on boots straight to the desktop.
Im guessing it would be done in autostart, but I cant figure out how,
does anybody know how this can be done?
Thanks

Comment: Just as a suggestion, I would install and use the new [Epiphany Browser](http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-released/) from the Pi Foundation/Collabora. It's more optimized for the Pi and is Faster, has Javascript capabilities, can play 720p video smoothly, and uses quite a bit less CPU than Midori; not to mention more technical things.

Comment: I'll have a look into that thanks, ideally I need to be able to boot straight to a fullscreen browser with 2 tabs open, which has the nav bar hidden but still shows the tab bar.

Comment: Opening the browser straight to two tabs shouldn't be too hard, however getting the software full-screen, might take some work. I'm not sure if Epiphany has full-screen capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You have an option to create a script running:

```
midori http://url1  http://url2   http://urln...
```